# How to keep sql tables in redis efficiently

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I searched on net but couldnt find any brieny description for it, so here its;

There is `Products` table, here is the example of 2 rows;

```
ID Name Price Expire CreatedDate ...
1  A    12    4      01.01.2019 
2  B    25    5      01.01.2019
```

there is 100 million more which needed to be searched and retrieve fast.

What I learn with some search Redis keeps data as JSON,

so I create a key composite of `tablename:row_primary_key` and write this 100 million rows from database to redis with keys as(and value is entire row serialized json string)

```
Products:1
Products:2
...
```

So I am able to get any particular row with key, but I think you asked the question at the moment what if I need make search with other columns, for example Price or Name?

What first thing to come in mind generate another 100 million in Redis with keys composite of 'tablename:price' but it sounds extremely frustrating and waste of memory(I don't say even when there is 10 more columns suppose to be in search).

So whats the best and most efficient way to store rows from SQL table in Redis?

And I am using StackExchange.Redis library.

Comment: Is there any reason you need to use Redis? It'd be helpful if you can describe in some more detail exactly what you're trying to accomplish and why SQL isn't sufficient.

Comment: @chris Well, there is a table with many rows oftenly searched but rarely updated so I think its good idea to keep this data in memory instead of disk

Comment: @TyForHelpDude it seems like what you're looking for is RediSearch